# Why might relection fail on vue computed property?

Tags: vue.js

Is there any reason why a VueJS computed property might not be able to directly access the wrapped objects properties?

```
const storageNode = computed(() => (
  {
    type: "Chicken",
    id: "probablyFake",
  }
)
...
const onButton = () => {
  const id = storageNode.id;  // is always undefined
  const vid = storageNode.value.id; // Is valid???
  ...
}
```

Background: I'm fairly new to VueJS, and have inherited a fairly messy project where properties etc are always accessed by `property.value`.  It's not a huge deal, but I was under the impression that computed properties are essentially proxy objects, and I could treat it the same.  It worries me that either I don't understand something fundamental, or perhaps we broke it, or some combo of the above.

Any idea's on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Your expectations are applicable to `reactive`, not `computed`. Computeds are refs. Computed values aren't necessarily objects, and there would be no chance for a primitive value to be reactive without wrapping it with a ref.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Does that mean I can't access a computed objects members directly?

In this case, I think dropping most of the computeds makes sense, AFAIK it seems mostly valuable as a caching mechanism or for updates, using it simply for value storage seems over-the-top

Comment: It's unknown what computeds are in your case and whether their use is justified. Yes, it doesn't make sense to use them for non-reactive values like in the code above, there's even eslint rule for that. Also `unref(storageNode)` is a cleaner alternative to using .value property everywhere, beneficial in places when you're not sure what is a ref and what is not.